# React native modularization

Tags: react-native, module, refactoring, lerna, modularization

Currently, I need to modularize an app into smaller modules. As far as I've known, modularization is the concept of separating an app into smaller components, which will be developed by a specific team. Finally, these modules will be merged into a complete production. However, my manager wants to review/test these modules as standalone apps. For example, we have authentication module and news module. Normally, user need to authenticate first, then navigate to the Main Screen (which contains News Module). But in my case, we want to test/review News Module without the authentication step as a standalone app.
Through my research, I've found a [library](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) for modularization. But i don't know if this library can match the above requirements. Is there a more official way to do this without creating many different repo/npm library for each module? Have any teams faced this kind of modularization before? Thank you in advance!